# Issue in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of Data that contains a list of machines with the following columns (good parts, bad parts, production date, end date, time/1pc = means time spent for one piece to make) these informations are used to calculate the 3 performance indicators in order to get the OEE for each machine.

I've created a user form that allows the user to enter the type of machine and the production date and by hiting ''OK'' the 3 indicators (availability, quality, performance) are calculated via a program in VBA excel. My Main objective is to create a dashboard that shows all these indicators plus the OEE for the type of machine selected by the user in a specific month I have created a worksheet for each machine containing in each column (the Month of the year the specific date, quality indicator, availability and performance and OEE) and by side there is a button that shows us a userform to select the week desired to calculate these indicators and there it goes my issue:

I'm trying to connect the userform before that calculate the indicators with this one that allows us to chose the week to fill the table for each machine with their indicators. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide code attempts and and images to allow the community to assist you

Comment: I can't add photos it says that i need 10 reviews or something like that !!!

Comment: add some code at least to show us what you have attempted so far towards a solution

Comment: Private sub userform_initialize() comobox1.List=worksheets(''sheet1'').Range(''C2:C60'') 
End sub 
private sub pointage() 
Dim cmp as integer , nb_ligne as integer , quality as double , performance as double ,availability as double , T1 as double , produc_min as double , good_parts as integer , produc_qua as Integer 
Quality=0
Performance=0
Availability=0
Cmp=0
Date1=1/1/1999
Date2=2/1/1999
Nb_ligne=sheets(''data'').Range(''A65536'').End(x1UP).Row
For i=2 to nb_ligne 
If sheets(''data'').cells(i,35).value<>'' '' and textbox1.value<> '' '' then

Comment: Date1=format(textbox1.value,''dd/mm/yy'')
Date2=format(sheets(''data'').cells(i,35),''dd/mm/yy'')
End if 
If combobox.value=sheets(''data'').cells(i,8) And date1=date2
T1=T1+ sheets(''data'').cells(i,36)-sheets(''data'').cells(i,35)
 Produc_min=produc_min+sheets(''data'').cells(i,23)*sheets(''data'')cells(i,22)
Good_parts=good_parts+sheets(''data'').cells(i,24)
Quality=good_parts/produc_qua
Availability=T1/460*3
Performance=produc_min/T1
Cmp=cmp+1
End if 
Next
If cmp=0 then cmp=1
End if 
Quality =quality/cmp
Availability=availability/cmp
Performance=performance/cmp

Comment: OEE= Quality *Availability *Performance
Textbox6=OEE
End sub 
Private sub commandbutton2_click ()
Unload me
End sub 
Private sub textbox1_change()
Dim valeur as byte 
Textbox1.Maxlength=10
Valeur = len (textbox1)
End sub 
Private sub commandbutton1_click ()
If not isdate (textbox1) then 
Msgbox ''format incorrect ''
Textbox1= '' ''
Else 
Pointage 
End if 
End sub

Comment: No, you need to `edit` your question, and add the code there, not here in the comments. to add the code in correct format, ensure you indent each line with 4 spaces. thanks

Comment: I did not found that code area !!!!